# Member object not found: no member named get_event(), Also dealing with polymorphism and vectors

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism, abstract-class

I am having trouble with my code:

```
    void room_encounter_randomizer(vector<vector<room> > *grid, int row, int col){//allocates events to the rooms.
    wumpus w1;
    int row_rand = rand() % row;
    int col_rand = rand() % col;
    for(int i =0 ; i < 4; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < row; j++){
            for(int k = 0; k < col; k++){
                grid[i][j].get_event() = &w1;
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

It is supposed to randomly assign events to each room. Here are my classes:

```
        class event{//abstract class
    public:
        virtual void percept() = 0;
        virtual void encounter() = 0;
    };

    class room{
    private:
        event* ev;
    public:
        event* get_event();

    };
```

```
event *room::get_event(){
    return ev;
}

class wumpus:public event{
    public:
        void percept();
        void encounter();

};

void wumpus::percept(){
    //if player is within a tile
    cout << "You smell a terrible stench..." << endl;
}
void wumpus::encounter(){
    cout << "The Wumpus eats you" << endl;
    exit(0);
}
void create_grid(){

}
```

But I get this error:

```
vectortest.cpp: In function ‘void room_encounter_randomizer(std::vector<std::vector<room> >*, int, int)’:
vectortest.cpp:78:16: error: ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<room> > >::value_type’ has no member named ‘get_event’
     grid[i][j].get_event() = &w1;
```

I'm not really sure what to think of it. Since I have all the code in one file, shouldn't that function be recognized, since it's public?

Also I'm not really sure how to deal with the abstract class, I figured I would try to set the room object event pointer equal to the `wumpus` reference.

Comment: `grid` is a pointer to a `vector` of `vectors`. Your double `[]` operator treats `grid` like an array of `vector`s of `vector`s, and takes the `j`th `vector` of the `i`th `vector`. You can solve this by dereferencing `grid` first: `(*grid)[i][j].event()`. Better yet, instead of passing all these pointers around, pass references.

Comment: And give your `room` class a `set_event` function instead of setting it like this.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
void room_encounter_randomizer(vector<vector<room> > &grid, int row, int col)
```

and pass `grid` as a reference rather than as a pointer.

## TL;DR version

`vector<vector<room> > *grid` is a pointer to a `vector` of `vector`s. Since pointers can be indexed like arrays (`p[i]` is defined by the C++ Standard as identical to `*(p+i)`)

```
grid[i] // is a vector<vector<int>>
grid[i][j] // is a vector<int>
grid[i][j][k] // is an int
```

The object at `grid` is most likely one `vector` of `vectors`, this will be fatal at runtime.